# redirect in setinterval within 1 sec javascript OR stop setinterval on condition

Tags: javascript

```
setInterval(function () {

//=======  

//code 

//======== 

if(--timer<0){ 
   timer=0;

   window.location = "logout.php?uid=<?php echo $uid ?>&etype=<?php echo $et ?>";
} 

},1000);
```

here afert timer over,instead of redirect same page reloading again and again.

Your any help will be appreciated.

Comment: You might want to use [setTimeOut](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_settimeout.asp) instead of `setInterval`.

Comment: no man its timer..after each one second timer decreses to 1

Comment: I suggest you read the documentation on [setInterval](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/met_win_setinterval.asp) to confirm if that's the behavior you want. From the docs "The `setInterval()` method will continue calling the function until `clearInterval()` is called, or the window is closed."

Comment: :(  how to put clearinterval inside setinterval :(  ...if it was as simple i would not be here

Comment: If you want the redirect to happen in 1 second, then you do not need to use `setInterval`. If you want something to happen **every** one second in a loop, then you use `setInterval`.

Comment: As far as your other question is concerned, You can simply do `var myVar = setInterval(function(){ //some code , 1000);` and then when you need to stop the loop, somewhere in some function that gets triggered, you simply call `clearInterval(myVar);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this

```js
var timer = 3;    //your timer length
var myVar = setInterval(function() {
  //code
  if (--timer < 0) {
    clearInterval(myVar);
    window.location = "logout.php?uid=<?php echo $uid ?>&etype=<?php echo $et ?>";
  }
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a *variable* for the *interval*. Use `clearInterval` to *delete* the *timer*.

```
var interval = setInterval(function(){
    if (true) doWhatShouldHappenIfTrue();
    else clearInterval(interval);
}, 1000);
```